# Inner div using 100% of height of an outer div that's % based itself

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.

I'm using a layout taking 100% height of the viewport. I do not want the page to scroll (it's an admin page).

Using the grid system, I created 2 rows taking 50% of the screen each. This works well.

Problem: Inside the single cells contained by these two rows I have placed content I want to overflow (scroll) as the screen is resized. Unfortunately, unless I assign a fixed height *in pixels* to this div, the content doesn't overflow.

Question: how can I make the overflowing content of the inner div take 100% of the height available to the cell, which itself if 50% of the total height of the screen?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanTual/nu83c/3/

```
<!-- Both section A and section B should take 100% of the height available to them.
The height available to each section is 50% of the total page height.
If either section contains more content that can fit, it should overflow: scroll -->


<div class="row full-height">

  <div class="col-md-3 full-height">

    <div class="row fifty-pc-height">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Title for Section A</h4>
        <div class="overflow-container">
           a<br>
           a<br>
           a<br>           
           a<br>
           a<br>
           a<br>
           a<br>           
           a<br>
           a<br>
           a<br>
           a<br>           
           a<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row fifty-pc-height">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Title for Section B</h4>
        <div class="overflow-container">
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
           b<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give `full-height` to the `col-md-12` div and let `overflow-container` have some percent thereof, it will scroll nicely

```html
<div class="row full-height">
  <div class="col-md-3 full-height">
    <div class="row fifty-pc-height">
      <div class="col-md-12 full-height">
        <h4>Title for Section A</h4>
        <div class="overflow-container">
        ...
```

```css
.overflow-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 70%;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu83c/4/)

*Update:*

If you're lucky to ignore older browser, you might try [`flexbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). You can add

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

to the `col-md-12` div

remove the

```
height: 70%;
```

from `overflow-container` and you're done, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu83c/5/)

You might even remove some `div` layers and reduce your HTML to

```html
<div class="full-height container">
    <div class="overflow-wrapper">
        <h4>Title for Section A</h4>
        <div class="overflow-container">
        ...
```

and let `flexbox` handle the outer and inner dimensions

```css
.container, .overflow-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.overflow-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu83c/6/)

Comment: Thanks for that Olaf, however, slight issue here: if the height is set to 100%, the overflow overlaps with the title. I suppose this is why you placed a value of 70% instead of 100%. As the height of the title in pixels is known, is there a way to somehow cater for this without risking a large white space?

Comment: If you have a fixed size title, you can play with `position: absolute` and `top: 30px; bottom: 0;` for example. But I haven't found a working solution.

Comment: Cheers Olaf, I found references to calc(100%-20px), but from my trials I couldn't find a working solution either as the 20px, albeit syntactically valid, didn't seem to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Hi Olaf, I tried flexbox and while it does work I am going with a jquery based solution for the 'pixel offset' issue. The reason is that while jquery is not a elegant as a full blown css solution, the jquery code allows for very accurate resizing of the elements down to a single pixel without much of a performance hit. The flexbox solution is likely 'better' syntactically, but it causes a number of issues in terms of element overlap, albeit slightly. Thank you for all your help and happy holidays!